# Array javascript filter

Tags: javascript

I have an array and i want to filter this array by Country and Service

i did the filter by Country but i want also do the same thing by service

this the array :

```
[
   {
      "Country":"CHINA",
      "details":"None",
      "Service":"BUSINESS",
   },
   {
      "Country":"USA",
      "details":"Bus-Trip",
      "Service":"BUSINESS",
   },
   {
      "Country":"USA",
      "details":"Comm-Trip",
      "Service":"COMMUNICATION",
   },

   ];
```

I was able to do that by this code

```
let objectData = Data.reduce(function (acc,cur) {  
    if (!acc[cur.Country])
    acc[cur.Country] =  { data : []};
    acc[cur.Country].data.push(cur)
    return acc;
},
{} );
```

the code above  allowed me to filter only by country and it's work but i want to do this same
thing by country and service BOTH and i want the result like this :

```
   [
    {
        Country :"CHINA",
        Service : [
            {"details":"None",}
        ] 
       },
       {
        Country :"USA" , 
        Service : [
            {"details":"Bus-Trip"},
            {"details":"Comm-Trip"}
        ]
       },
       
   ]
```

Comment: I don't understand correct, do you want to strip service value?

Comment: Yes  like the example above

Comment: I think using `filter`, or `map` would be better in this case

Comment: This isn't filtering. Filtering is just returning array elements that match some criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Some slight modifications to your new object for each country so it reflects what you want and then use Object.values() to get the expected results array

```js
let grouped = Data.reduce(function (acc,{Country, ...rest}) {        
    acc[Country] = acc[Country] || {Country, Services : []};
    acc[Country].Services.push(rest)
    return acc;
},{} );

const res = Object.values(grouped)

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
const Data=[{Country:"CHINA",details:"None",Service:"BUSINESS"},{Country:"USA",details:"Bus-Trip",Service:"BUSINESS"},{Country:"USA",details:"Comm-Trip",Service:"COMMUNICATION"}];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
objectData = Data.reduce(function (acc,cur) {  
    if (!acc[cur.Country])
      acc[cur.Country] =  [];
    acc[cur.Country].push({details: cur.details});
    return acc;
}, {} );
objectData = Object.keys(objectData).map(key => ({
  Country: key,
  Service: objectData[key]
}));
```

You first need to modify the reduce code a bit, to contain details data only because you want to strip services.
At this moment, country will be key, so you need one more step to convert objectData to the desired format.
Object.keys(objectData) returns all countries list without duplication, so the second part finally builds the format you require.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free coding service, please explain your answer.